# How to solve $6^{2x} = 5^{x-2}$ for $x$

Tags: logarithms

I have recently come across this problem in my homework and I'm finding it quite difficult to solve. The simplest answer would be preferred using exponential laws and logarithms.

Comment: Consider the logarithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}6^{2x}&=5^{x-2}\\
\log\left(6^{2x}\right)&=\log\left(5^{x-2}\right)\\
2x\log(6)&=(x-2)\log(5)\tag{$\dagger$}\\
2x\log(6)&=x\log(5)-2\log(5)\\
x\log(5)-2x\log(6)&=2\log(5)\\
x\left(\log(5)-2\log(6)\right)&=2\log(5)\\
x&=\frac{2\log(5)}{\log(5)-2\log(6)}\end{align}

---

$(\dagger)$ We have used the rule that $\log\left(a^b\right)=b\log(a)$

Comment: Excuse me, for some reason I had a mental blank and could not solve the equation. It bothered me for so long and the answer is so simple! I'm face palming right now. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @JamesBalajan No worries, glad I could help jog your memory

Answer (score 2):

$6^{2x} = 5^{x-2} \iff 36^x=5^x* \frac{1}{25} \iff (\frac{36}{5})^x=\frac{1}{25} $

logarithm ...........

Comment: $6^{2x} \neq 12^x$

Comment: Ooops ! an edit will follow

Comment: $6^{2x} = (6^2)^x$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. By taking the logarithm of both sides we get the equivalent equation
$$2x\ln(6)=\ln(6^{2x})=\ln(5^{x-2})=(x-2)\ln(5).$$ 
Are you able to find $x$ now?